# Stacked Bar Plot in ggplot for Binary Counts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c("O", "C", "In", 
"In", "C", "C", "C",
```

s"), V2 = c("0",
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0",
"0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
"0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-50L))

I want to create a stacked bar plot for each speciality `(V1)` that sums the number of 0's and 1's `(shown in V2).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(V1 = c("Orthopedics", "Cardiac", "Interventional Radiology", 
                            "Interventional Radiology", "Cardiac", "Cardiac", "Cardiac", 
                            "Urology", "Cardiac", "Orthopedics", "Cardiac", "Neurosurgery", 
                            "Cardiac", "Transplant", "Gynecology", "Cardiac", "Interventional Radiology", 
                            "Interventional Radiology", "Cardiac", "Cardiac", "Urology", 
                            "Vascular", "Neurosurgery", "Cardiac", "Cardiac", "Cardiac", 
                            "Cardiac", "Cardiac", "General", "Cardiac", "Urology", "Cardiac", 
                            "Interventional Radiology", "Neurosurgery", "Cardiac", "Cardiac", 
                            "Urology", "Urology", "Thoracic", "Cardiac", "Neurosurgery", 
                            "Urology", "Cardiac", "Urology", "Neurosurgery", "Neurosurgery", 
                            "Orthopedics", "Cardiac", "Cardiac", "Orthopedics"), V2 = c("0", 
                                                                                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                                                                        "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                                                                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                                                                        "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                -50L))

df |> 
  group_by(V1, V2) |> 
  tally() |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = V1,
             y = n,
             fill = V2)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>